# Routes probleme with an Angular 5 project

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, dashboard

Well I'm new with Angular and I'm trying to use this project :

https://github.com/telerik/ng2-dashboard

But I could not understand how routes are made. That's not the way that I'm used to doing with Routes.

Even when I have added something to the Sign in Component it redirects me straight to the dashboard!

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know what your exact issues are, but it looks like from the github project you provided, the signin component has a hard coded user in it that should be causing you to redirect to /profile. You could either use the signout functionality to stop it from happening if you want to go back to the signout component or clear your browser cache/cookies.

The routing on the other hand it looks like a master route file that branches out to sub modules that have their own routes. I'll try to show how everything connects in a poor arrow diagram...

```
app.module.ts --gets all routes--> app.common.ts 
app.common.ts --calls master route module --> app-routing.module.ts 
app-routing.module.ts --gets parent component/routes--> app.route.ts 
app.route.ts --calls all child modules --> ex.dashboard.module.ts
ex: dashboard.module.ts -- gets child routes/components --> ex: dashboard.common.ts
ex: dashboard.common.ts --gets child routes --> ex: dashboard.routes.ts
ex: dashboard.routes -- sets/creates child routes --
```

hope this kinda helps and gives you a better understanding of how this project create routes.

Answer (score -1):

I think, @HostBinding is listening globally in below two files:-

signin.component.ts file

```
@HostBinding('attr.id') protected get id(): string {
        return 'signin';
}
@HostBinding('class') protected get appClass(): string {
        return 'signin';
}
```

dashboard.component.ts file,

```
@HostBinding('attr.id') get get_id() { return 'dashboard'; }
@HostBinding('class') get get_class() { return 'dashboard'; }
```

Can you try to **comment those lines for @HostBinding in dashboard.component.ts** and try to test again. Hope it will work.

Comment: Same problem , even if i add the http service in the constructor the 'main page' become my first page not sign in !